# How fragile is my Mustang "Pro Guitar" controller?

Tags: rock-band-3

I got the 102-button "Mustang" guitar for Rock Band 3, and I'm kind of afraid I'm going to break it if I breathe on it too hard. (Possibly I'm just having bad memories of the hardware issues at RB1's launch.)

In particular, the strings feel awful flimsy. Does anyone know how they're constructed, or how much force they're designed to take? Are there play styles which are known to be bad for the Mustang or, alternately, cases of them taking a beating and still being totally usable? Should fingers vs. pick matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also have a Mustang Pro Guitar and it's far too new for *anyone* to tell if it will be durable or not. I would give it the benefit of the doubt and assume it will be durable until the community proves otherwise.

In other words, check back here in a year. :)

Also I found the guitar almost unplayable without a pick. My fingers are nowhere near precise enough to hit specific strings.. so I always use a pick, and the guitar manual recommends you use a pick as well (the guitar itself comes with 2 picks in the plastic bag containing the manual.)

Comment: I don't play Pro Guitar often, but when I do, I tend to play without a pick ... maybe because as a bassist, I'm accustomed to fingers rather than pick anyway. I also play Pro Guitar on Easy or Medium, so that probably makes a difference as well. The one thing about picking with fingers is that it seems to take very little force at all; too much and sometimes I end up "strumming" an adjacent string as well.

Comment: Hey, it's been a year plus. How's that Mustang holding up?

Comment: @chuck I honestly haven't played it a lot, plus, I got the (now discontinued) Fender Squier guitar as well, so that vies for the same time..

Comment: My Mustang is holding up okay, but while it's not that bad I'm really regretting not having gotten the Squier now. (Desperately trying to find a cheap one, but they're $400+ now!)